# Can't get onCreate function to trigger using TypeScript on Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set up a function in Cloud Firestore that will trigger whenever a new document is added to a particular collection. I wish to do it using TypeScript as I'm told its easier to work with when writing asynchronous code. The following JavaScript code works as expected and triggers whenever I add a new document at the specified location:

```
//This JavaScript code works
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

exports.waitReportCreatedJS = functions.firestore
    .document('merchant_locations/{merchantId}/wait_period/{waitId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        console.log('WaitReportCreated has been triggered');
        const merchantId = context.params.merchantId
        const waitId = context.params.waitId
        console.log(`New wait recorded: ${waitId} at ${merchantId}`);
        return snapshot.ref.update({ waitId: waitId })        

      });
```

But then when I try to do the same thing using TypeScript, it fails to trigger - nothing at all happens when I add the document:

```
//But this TypeScript code doesn't seem to even trigger
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const waitReportCreatedTS = functions.database
.ref('merchant_locations/{merchantId}/wait_period/{waitId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    console.log('WaitReportCreated has been triggered');
    const merchantId = context.params.merchantId
    const waitId = context.params.waitId
    console.log(`New wait recorded: ${waitId} at ${merchantId}`);
    return snapshot.ref.update({ waitId: waitId })
})
```

I'm very new to Firestore functions, and have no clue at all what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: `functions.firestore != functions.database`.  Different database products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript example you faciliate the Firestore Database `functions.firestore
    .document`. However your TypeScript example is using the Realtime Database `functions.database.ref`.

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const waitReportCreatedTS = functions.firestore
    .document('merchant_locations/{merchantId}/wait_period/{waitId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    console.log('WaitReportCreated has been triggered');
    const merchantId = context.params.merchantId
    const waitId = context.params.waitId
    console.log(`New wait recorded: ${waitId} at ${merchantId}`);
    return snapshot.ref.update({ waitId: waitId })
```